# On mac, lsof says a port is not in use, but I can telnet to the port

Tags: macos, telnet, lsof

If I run lsof, it says that this port is not in use.  Yet, I can telnet into it and something is listening on that port.

Am I using the wrong command to see what ports are in use?  I'd like to kill the process listening on 3306.

```
±  |master ✓| → lsof -i :3306

  |2.3.1| montana in ~/workspace
±  |master ✓| → telnet localhost 3306
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
J
5.6.39|=X%N9r�&a;AtF>E!r>{mysql_native_passwordConnection closed by foreign host.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check which process is running on 3306 port
sudo lsof -i tcp:3306
and if you get the process id
kill -9

Comment: Ah OK, I needed the sudo.  Thanks